# access root file from subdomain in PHP

Tags: php, include, subdomain, root

Is it possible to include file from the ftp's root in a script in a subdomain ?

This doesn't work for me:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/joomla.php');
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Have you checked that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` points where you think it does?

Comment: In my other folders it works anyway, but not in the subdomains!

Comment: Try `include(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/joomla.php');` or `include('../joomla.php');`

Comment: Again, output the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and see if it's the right location for the file. It likely is the document root for the subdomain, not your main domain. You'd need to find the path to the main domain and use that.

Comment: still no succes... it shows the path of the subdomain map...

Comment: @user3408380 So, find the actual path to the file you want and use that.

Comment: The subdomain, parent domain, and FTP root can each be placed literally anywhere on your server (or even on different servers).  Without knowing more about your folder structure, this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think first you need to determine where is your subdomain files are placed and echo the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] command to see the full path then you can combine two paths and make necessary adjustments.

Usually but not always, subdomain files are placed in a folder one level up then the main site's root folder so you may need to replace the folder name according to your needs in the output of server document folder function.

To give an example if your domain files are in a path like

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/
```

and if your subdomain path is like

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomain/
```

then you will need to replace httpdocs with subdomain (or the other way around) in the output where you call $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']